# setattr doesn't update the correct attribute of a class when using string

Tags: python, string, setattr

I'm trying to update an attribute of a class with `setattr` and a string. So for instance with this code:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 0

class ClassB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.CA = ClassA()

CB = ClassB()
setattr(CB, "CA.A", 2)

print(CB.CA.A)
```

when I do `setattr(CB, "CA.A", 2)`, it doesn't update the attribute `A` of the `CA` class in`CB`. Instead, it creates another attribute, as in the picture:

[image] in the class `CB` named `CA.A`

Then when I print `print(CB.CA.A)`, I get a 0 value.
I don't understand why this happend and if a solution exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setattr()` takes a *literal attribute name*. It does not support nested attributes; the `.` in the name is *just a dot in the name*, not an attribute separator.

Put differently, `.` in `CB.CA.A = 2` is *syntax to access attributes*, not part of the attribute name. `CB.CA` is looked up first, and then the assignment takes place to the `A` attribute on the result.

You need to split on the `.` and use a separate `getattr()` call to obtain the parent object first:

```
setattr(getattr(CB, 'CA'), "A", 2)
```

You could wrap that logic into a function:

```
def setattr_nested(base, path, value):
    """Accept a dotted path to a nested attribute to set."""
    path, _, target = path.rpartition('.')
    for attrname in path.split('.'):
        base = getattr(base, attrname)
    setattr(base, target, value)
```

Comment: Ho, I see. I like the inception function :)

Comment: However If i try to create a variable with a dot in the name, it will give me an error. So why when I use `setattr` it creates an attribute with a dot in it name

Comment: @ymmx: normally, syntax restricts you to valid Python identifiers (which can't include dots). That's because dots have special meaning. But `setattr()` and `getattr()` are not restricted to such names, you can use any string.

Comment: That's a bit at odds with `operator.attrgetter` that does support dots

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D `operator.attrgetter()` is what is the special case here.